# Leaflet : Can't Find Events For The Zoom Buttons Clicks

Tags: maps, zooming, leaflet

**What I'm Trying To Do:**

It would be nice to customize the zoom events a bit when the user clicks the zoom in or zoom out buttons.

**Problem:**

I can't find the events that are tied to the zoom in and out buttons. I've been reading the docs and the only thing I find is `zoomstart` and `zoomend`.

**Question:**

**Are there events tied to those zoom buttons? If so, can they be used to intercept zooms beforehand to customize the zooming?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no events firing from the zoomcontrol. Only from the map itself when it zooms in or out. If you need to hook something onto the zoomin button:

```
var element = document.querySelector('a.leaflet-control-zoom-in');

L.DomEvent.addListener(element, 'click', function (e) {
    console.log('Got clicked:', e)
});
```

But remember, the zoom can be changed programmaticly, by scroll, by...

Comment: Another great solution! Thanks @iH8 !